# How to debug myBatis NoSuchMethodException in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, mybatis

I have a simple class like this:

```
data class Foo(
        val id: Long,
        val created: LocalDateTime,
        val myBool: Boolean? = null,
        val comment: SensitiveString? = null
)
```

I get the exception:

```
org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: Error instantiating class com.XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.Foo with invalid types (long,LocalDateTime,boolean,SensitiveString) or values (XX,2020-03-19T17:36:30.415,false,0@SensitiveString). 
Cause: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.Foo.<init>(long, java.time.LocalDateTime, boolean, com.XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.SensitiveString)
```

Here is my xml resultMap:

```
<resultMap id="fooMap" type="com.XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.Foo">
        <constructor>
            <arg column="id" javaType="_long"/>
            <arg column="created" javaType="java.time.LocalDateTime"
                 typeHandler="com.XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.LocalDateTimeTypeHandler"/>
            <arg column="myBool" javaType="_Boolean"/>
            <arg column="comment" javaType="com.XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.SensitiveString"
                typeHandler="com.XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.EncryptedStringTypeHandler"/>
        </constructor>
    </resultMap>
```

How can I solve this? the asked constructor should definitely be available, so it is very confusing.
Moreover: when I try to create my own constructor with all the fields then kotlin complains saying the constructor is conflicting with the implicit one.

How can I tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this exact problem. The issue for me was the `Boolean?` type - the Java type is `java.lang.Boolean` when the type is nullable. I did it with annotations, so it would look like this:

```kotlin
    @ConstructorArgs (
        ...
        Arg(column = "myBool", javaType = java.lang.Boolean::class)
        ...
    )
```

Comment: Thank you! changing ``_Boolean`` to ``Boolean`` fixed it!